# Handler gets called early before for loop has finished processing Firebase snasphot in swift, why?

Tags: swift

I need some help, I have the following code which is part of function that queries and returns a `snapshot` of user data from `Firebase`. I am trying to loop through the `snapshot` passing it to a helper `filterDiscoveredUserByPreferences` method that assists in filtering in/out then it is suppose to be adding the object to an array so that it can be passed back via a `handler`.

The issue is that my `handler` gets called too early way before the `for` loop has finished with the snapshot returned from `Firebase`. I have tried using `distpatchQueue` but that didn't work.

```
self.getUsersAtVenueHandle = self.REF_USERS.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

                    guard let usersSnapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else { return }


                        for user in usersSnapshot{
                            // Code here to get all values from ‘user’ snapshot the create User object

                            let user = User(uid: uid, dictionary: dictionary)

                            if user.discoverable == true && user.uid != Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {

                                self.filterDiscoveredUserByPreferences(discoveredUser: user, handler: { (success) in

                                    if success {
                                        users.append(user)
                                    }

                                })//filterDiscoveredUserByPreferences

                            }//end if

                        }//end for

                        //handler gets called before for loops has finished processing the entire snapshot

                        handler (users, true)
                        users.removeAll()


                }, withCancel: { (error) in
                    print(error)

                })//end Firebase call
```

Function: filterDiscoveredUserByPreferences

```
func filterDiscoveredUserByPreferences(discoveredUser: User, handler: @escaping (Bool) -> ()){

    let discoveredGender = discoveredUser.gender
    let discoveredPrefs: [String : Any] = discoveredUser.discoveryPrefs
    let discoveredPreferMen = discoveredPrefs["men"] as? Bool
    let discoveredPreferWomen = discoveredPrefs["women"] as? Bool

    var discoveredPreferredGender: String?

    switch (discoveredPreferMen, discoveredPreferWomen) {

    case (true, true):
        discoveredPreferredGender = "both"

    case (true, false):
        discoveredPreferredGender = "female"

    case (false, true):
        discoveredPreferredGender = "male"

    case (false, false):
        discoveredPreferredGender = "not discoverable"

    default:
        break
    }//end switch


    getUserInfo(forUserId: (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!) { (user) in

        let myGender = user.gender
        let myDiscoveryPrefs: [String : Any] = user.discoveryPrefs
        let myPreferMen = myDiscoveryPrefs["men"] as? Bool
        let myPreferWomen = myDiscoveryPrefs["women"] as? Bool


        switch (myPreferWomen, myPreferMen) {

        case (true, true): //both

            switch myGender {

            case "male":

                switch(discoveredPreferredGender){

                case "male":
                    handler(true)

                case "female":
                    handler(false)

                case "both":
                    handler(true)

                case "not discoverable":
                    handler(false)

                default:
                    break

                }//end switch

            case "female":

                switch(discoveredPreferredGender){

                case "male":
                    handler(false)

                case "female":
                    handler(true)

                case "both":
                    handler(true)

                case "not discoverable":
                    handler(false)

                default:
                    break

                }//end switch

            default:
                break

            }//end switch



        case (true, false)://female only

            if discoveredGender == "male"{
              handler(false)
            } else {

                switch(discoveredPreferredGender){

                case "male":
                    handler(true)

                case "female":
                    handler(false)

                case "both":
                    handler(true)

                case "not discoverable":
                    handler(false)

                default:
                    break

                }//end switch

            }//end else

        case (false, true): //male only

            if discoveredGender == "female"{
                handler(false)
            } else {

                switch(discoveredPreferredGender){

                case "male":
                    handler(true)

                case "female":
                    handler(false)

                case "both":
                    handler(true)

                case "not discoverable":
                    handler(false)

                default:
                    break

                }//end switch

            }//end else

        case (false, false): //none

            handler(false)

        default:
            break
        }


    }//end getLoggedinUserDetails


}//end fun
```

Func getUserInfo

```
func getUserInfo(forUserId: String, currentUserHandler: @escaping (_ currentUser: User) -> ()){

    REF_USERS.child(uid).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        guard let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }

        let user = User(uid: uid, dictionary: dict)

        currentUserHandler(user)

    }) { (error) in
        print(error)
    }

}//end func
```

Comment: You call the handler at every loop, so it will likely be called at least once before you finish looping. Is this what you meant to do?

Comment: no, i'm meant to call the handler just once when i finish processing the snapshot...i I thought bu calling the handler outside the `for` loop I was achieving that, is that not the case?

Comment: Do you mean this handler: `self.filterDiscoveredUserByPreferences(discoveredUser: user, handler: `? Because that is certainly in the for loop.

Comment: every `User` object gets passed to `filterDiscoveredUserByPreferences`, a `Bool` is returned, and if `true` then append to array, so yes it is suppose to run at every loop. But the `handler (users, true)` is only suppose to execute when the for loop has finished all iterations.

Comment: Is filterDiscoveredUserByPrefrence synchronous?

Comment: :/ how do I tell?..it is a long functions that does a lot of checks to determine if it should be included or not by returning a `Bool`...I have edited my question to include it in full.

Comment: I’d check, but getUserInfo looks asynchronous

Comment: I've edited my question to include it, I simply `observe` a user node in Firebase and return the values. -- what am I looking for that determines if it is asynchronous or not?

Comment: If you are accessing the fire base server, then that is an asynchronous component, so it runs on a background thread and the loop doesn’t wait for it to finish.

Answer (score 0):

It is async call back, it will get called multiple times, depending on the updates.
If you use debug breakpoints to examine this, you may get confused. Write a console log in the beginning and the end of the `observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) }` closure,  and you will understand the flow. It is impossible to call the handler before completing the for loop.
It could be your first callback has a large number of records and second callback has zero DataSnapshot s

Comment: _It is impossible to call the handler before completing the for loop_...that's the thing, I DON'T want to call the `handler` before the `for` loop finishes looping through the `snapshot`. I want to call it once but only after it has finished iterating through the `snapshot`